# Define custom MSBuild target that should execute after successful project Publish via context menu in VS 2019

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm trying to define a custom `<Target>` in my .csproj file that should run after a successful Publish of the project. I've tried these, but none of them get called:

```
<Target Name="MyTarget" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
   ...
</Target>

<Target Name="MyTarget" AfterTargets="Publish">
   ...
</Target>

<Target Name="AfterPublish">
   ...
</Target>
```

If, OTOH, I try to hook up to an AfterBuild target, everything works as expected. Unfortunately, I don't want my target to run after each build. I only want it to run after I publish the project, which is currently a manual operation - i.e. I'm not using any CI/CD, ClickOnce, WebDeploy, or any other automation pipeline for that matter.

From what I've read on the internet, this might be what's tripping me up, because BeforePublish/AfterPublish tasks seem not to be triggered by the context menu option (i.e. Solution Explorer -> right-click on my project -> Publish...). I still have my doubts, though, because after the manual publish, the Output panel contains publishing information that looks like it probably came from a .targets file somewhere.

FWIW, my publishing profile is defined to output the app to a local folder.

What would be the correct way to get my custom target to execute in this scenario?

Comment: [MSBuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019) spec says that `Publish` target is for clickonce only. Which publish do you use?

Comment: I just select Solution Explorer -> right-click on my project -> Publish... I have no idea what it calls under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by switching project type to a .NET Framework Console App (originally, I had a .NET Core Console App) and hooking onto the ClickOnce's AfterPublish target.

I think it's really odd that .NET Core projects can't hook onto MSBuild publish-related targets, since the Publish command is readily available in the Solution Explorer's context menu. It's also the only way to deploy to multiple platforms, where having various custom after-targets would be extremely useful. Maybe I'm missing something, but it really looks like an oversight...

Luckily, I don't care which project type I choose in this particular case, so .NET Framework & ClickOnce combination is completely fine. I only need my target to run when I do a Publish and it works now.